# Getting a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused error in github action?

Tags: laravel, github-actions

This is what my actions look like, when I get to the point of `php artisan test` I get the error:

```
   name: Continuous Integration

on:
  push
jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    - name: create migration
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: php artisan migrate --seed
    - name: run tests
      run: php artisan test
```

Comment: I don't know how these actions work, but are the environment variables you set in the previous step carried over, or do you need to re-specify them?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on [steps](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps):

> Each step runs in its own process in the runner environment and has access to the workspace and filesystem. Because steps run in their own process, changes to environment variables are not preserved between steps.

So you'll need to provide the environment variables for the entire workflow, as described in the documentation for [environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) and [the `jobs.<job_id>.env` keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv):

```yaml
name: Continuous Integration
on:
  push
jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    ...
```